# Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) can be assumed as Middlware Technology

Tags: .net, wcf

I have know that Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a code library to connect between different applications. I have once used Inter-Process Communication technology to connect two different applications written in two different languages (vb.net and C#.net). Therefore, I want to know that

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) of .Net Framework can be assumed as Middleware Technology for .Net Applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, middleware is a piece of software that runs independently of other software. Programs can connect to this software. WCF does not do this. It integrates with existing applications and offers interfaces for communication with these. Therefore, it is not really middleware. However, it can be utilized to create middleware programs.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting article:

- [The origin of the term "middleware"](http://ironick.typepad.com/ironick/2003/11/the_origin_coin.html).

> It would appear that the term Middleware was coined by Alex
>   d'Agapeyeff at the NATO Conference on Software Engineering in Garmisch
>   Partenkirchen, Germany in 1968. See Page 23 of Brian Randall's and
>   Peter Naur's Report at
>   http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/brian.randell/NATO/.

For whatever it's worth, the term is too vague to give a definite "yes" or "no" answer.

But I'm inclined to agree with Nico Schertler - there's nothing "independent" about WCF (it's all Microsoft: top, bottom, forward and backward), so it really doesn't "bridge" anything.  Which is exactly what I'd ordinarily expect "middleware" to do.

IMHO...